# OneDrive: GPO - automatically insert team site libraries for synchronization

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, synchronisation, group-policy

I have a question regarding Sharepoint and Group policies (gpo) (section: Configure team site libraries to sync automatically):

Here's the explaination what my topic is about: we have an online sharepoint account, where customer data is saved. Every customer gets its own document library. Creating each library is done by an uploading tool, which loads new customer data from the local server database into sharepoint using the graph api. In the same moment when a document library is created the tool should tell the local server group policies in the section 'Configure team site libraries to sync automatically', that this new library should be synchronized to the local server one-drive folder.

We know that it is possible to do this manually. You have to go to the concerned document library in sharepoint, klick on synchronize above, the onedrive app reacts and creates the local folder, then a pop up appears where you can copy the library id, and this value must be copied into the 'Configure team site libraries to sync automatically' - list. So the sharepoint-library and the one-drive-folder are synchronized now.

Here's my gpo-tutorial i used:
[onedrive-gpo-configure-team-site-libraries-to-sync-automatically](https://hansbrender.com/2019/03/27/onedrive-gpo-configure-team-site-libraries-to-sync-automatically/)

So my first question is:
how to do this absolutely automatically?
We already can build this library-id what should be inserted into the gpo. Now the central question is, how can we get this string into the 'Configure team site libraries to sync automatically' - list.

Second question:
I heard about the WMI and that this could help us. Is this right? But i am not familiar with this. Does anyone know a good WMI-Tutorial?

Thank you very much!!
Greetings, Klemens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LGPO helped me out here:

[how-to-individually-modify-and-deploy-local-gpo-settings-lgpo](https://brookspeppin.com/2018/11/04/how-to-individually-modify-and-deploy-local-gpo-settings-lgpo/)